# How to debug BIOS ROM incompatibility?

Tags: rom, ibm, bios, xt-ide

I'd like to use the XT-IDE Universal BIOS with an IBM XT 286 (5162), but it's [known to be incompatible](http://minuszerodegrees.net/xtide/XT-IDE%20-%20Problems.htm). With the card installed, it will not boot from a floppy from which it would otherwise boot (it starts to, but then glitches out).

I plan to try third-party system BIOSes to see if that might fix it, but while I wait for EEPROMs to show up, I thought it might be worthwhile to see if I can fix whatever incompatibility there is directly. The [source code](https://github.com/aunali1/xtideuniversalbios) seems unmaintained, though I did try flashing the latest version just in case (it has the same problem).

I'm a professional programmer by day with quite a lot of experience at low-level programming, but no experience with my new (to me) IBM or computers of its era. If I wanted to debug this problem, how might I start?

Comment: XT-IDE BIOS author started troubleshooting that, btw -- <http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?59302-Getting-extremely-frustrated-with-nonfunctional-IDE-options-on-a-5170-5162/page5 .   The problem manifests as "It initially appears to work, but reads are randomly corrupted. Later revisions of the 5170 BIOS reduce the corruption, but it's still there. " (from same thread)

Comment: From above thread, at least one person who got XT-IDE working on a 5162 describes the process: http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?59302-Getting-extremely-frustrated-with-nonfunctional-IDE-options-on-a-5170-5162&p=474190#post474190

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and tried it. Doesn't work for me, for whatever reason. :'( I replied to the thread about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your skill level and the hardware you have access to, there are a few possible approaches I can think of:

- you could read the code for the various BIOSs involved and try to figure out the incompatibility that way
- you could use an in-circuit emulator to debug the problem
- you could use a bus sniffer such as [reenigne’s](https://www.reenigne.org/blog/isa-bus-sniffer-update/) to trace the system booting

As you can imagine, none of these are simple...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose what I would try is moving all the involved ROMs to RAM (a simple byte-copy routine can handle this), but then you would need to search for absolute jumps and retarget them to whatever RAM region you copied to.

Then, write a program that soft-boots the machine (either invoke the appropriate interrupt, or simulate what the CPU does at startup), then run this program under a debugger that lets you single-step through code. (this is why you needed to copy the ROM to RAM, so that you can set breakpoints).